# Iterating over every pair of elements in a Map

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I have a Map which holds Shape object values with their id as key.
I need to iterate over every pair of Shapes in this Map, but I want to iterate over each pair only once.

I know I can use forEach or for..of, but I can't find a way to prevent duplicate pairs. Also, this should be a as efficient as possible.

```
shapes.forEach((shape1, shapeId1) => {
    shapes.forEach((shape2, shapeId2) => {
        // iterating over each pair many times
    });
});
```

Comment: how do you feel about plain `for` loops?  Or do you need to use methods like `forEach()`?

Comment: I need to keep the functionality of the Map to allow me accessing Shapes by id (Shapes are removed and added to the ids are not sequential)

Comment: You should be able to hold onto your `Map` even if you iterate over its `entries()` output.  But, why does your map have objects as *keys* and ids as *values*?  If you want to look up objects by id, the id should be the key and the object should be the value.

Comment: You are correct, I accidentally switched between key and value. (edited original post)

Comment: Okay I will change my answer then to match it (and you should change `(shape1, shapeId1)` to `(shapeId1, shape1)` in your question, and likewise with `2`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest first converting the `Map` to an array of its entries:

```
const entryArray = Array.from(shapes.entries());
```

Then you can choose to iterate pairs either via traditional `for` loop:

```
console.log("FOR LOOP");
for (let i = 0; i < entryArray.length; i++) {
  const [shapeId1, shape1] = entryArray[i];
  for (let j = i + 1; j < entryArray.length; j++) {
    const [shapeId2, shape2] = entryArray[j];
    console.log(shapeId1, shapeId2);
  }
}
```

Or via the functional `forEach` array methods:

```
console.log("FOREACH");
entryArray.forEach(([shapeId1, shape1], i) =>
  entryArray.slice(i + 1).forEach(([shapeId2, shape2]) => {
    console.log(shapeId1, shapeId2);
  })
);
```

In each case you are avoiding duplicates by the inner loop only iterating the elements  *after* the outer loop index.  I don't know what your `Shape` or id types look like, but given this:

```
interface Shape {
  area: number;
}

const shapes: Map<string, Shape> = new Map([
  ["a", { area: 1 }],
  ["b", { area: 2 }],
  ["c", { area: 3 }]
]);
```

The above code outputs

```
FOR LOOP
a b
a c
b c
FOREACH
a b
a c
b c
```

So you can see that you get distinct pairs.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?strictNullChecks=false&jsx=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoAs4AcUG8BQyycUEcAXMiAK4C2ARtANz4C+++CA9iAM5jJemHL0oBZbAB5+UUAHMANGmEQAfMgC8VCAHdkErAAoA2oWTGARHAtLcxUhWQBGZKwC6Cs5fo3kdkmSUAEyuHl4WCL7+DpQAzKH4bgCULJw8-MgQ4FAAngCCUFBwOZrIBUU5AHQwUFy0hkLYELyVWWCyzYZJKRzcfFwANhCVA1xyhhYAYgDyAErIADLT0wAKFj0wXFDIhkMCwKUADEzIB5KZ2fmFxSNZcmDoJ8AA1M9JfmZ9GcaNOACSABMnEpfhAnG5Sm1cuVisZgG4WERNttdhABAArUoHZ7OE6Y85Qq4VW4ge6PZDo17vAhEIhfAQ-FSAoIglRBCFaQkwnLGdEIsx09KDYajcagwHAwRMgFBHpEdjsNL9IYjMYTGazACieQAwgAJdYsLnXKrIzWIdCGEzioGsprgpTAd4aVRmY3E3gDYBIQzY5xJapbc0IS3W6UsqVNdnO9Q02lfYWqsXSyU22WI1xJfA9IA)

Answer (score 0):

Use a Set with the two indexes:

```
let indexes = new Set();

shapes.forEach((shape1, shapeId1) => {

    shapes.forEach((shape2, shapeId2) => {

        if (set.has(`${shapeId1}-${shapeId2}`) || set.has(`${shapeId2}-${shapeId1}`)) return;
        set.add(`${shapeId1}-${shapeId2}`);

    });

});
```

Comment: This will still run over each pair more than once

Comment: Fixed @Guy, better now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use two for iterations using an index and start the nested iteration from the root index + 1. This will ensure you that you will never process two pairs.

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4];


for (let i = 0; i<arr.length-1; i++) {
  for (let j = i+1; j<arr.length; j++) {
    console.log(`${arr[i]} - ${arr[j]}`)
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the result that I'm looking for but I have a Map, not an array.

Comment: You can convert your map to an array: `const arr = Array.from(myMap.values())`